# Почему не работает такой ajax запрос?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

У меня есть простой ajax запрос, который передает сервлету данные, а сервлет в независимости от этих данных в ответ посылает строку. Почему, не смотря на то, что ajax запрос *успешно* передает данные сервлету, у него каждый раз срабатывает функция `error`, как если бы запрос был не успешным?

Код скрипта

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#login-button").click(function () {
                var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
                var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login",
                    data: {login: userLogin, password: userPassword},
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Successful request!");
                        if (data == "1") {
                            document.location.href = "http://localhost:8181/library/library.html";
                        }
                        if (data == "2") {
                            document.location.href = "http://localhost:8181/library/library.html";
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error report\n" + "jqXHR = " + jqXHR.responseText + "\n" + "textStatus = " + textStatus + "\n" +
                                "errorThrown =  " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Код сервлета

```
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    SocketConnection.output.println("log_in " + login + " " + password);
    //ajax запрос присылает корректные значения, все хорошо
    //попытка отослать обратно строку
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().println("1");
}
```

UPD. Сообщение в `alert`, `textStatus` имеет значение `error`, `errorThrown` пусто, `jqXHR.status = 0`.

UPD 2. Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Comment: почти прекрасный вопрос. Что же Вы сообщение из alert'а не привели?

Comment: Добавил сообщение

Comment: у jqXHR должен быть statusCode(). Код ошибки (или успеха). По нему сразу видно какого характера проблема

Comment: Код ошибки равен 0

Comment: добавьте `console.log(jqXHR);` в код обработчика `error` и скопируйте результат из консоли браузера в вопрос

Comment: Добавил результат из консоли в вопрос

Comment: Надо глянуть что происходит в сети. В инструментах разработчика браузера. Может запрос не отправляется, может ответ не приходит. Такого статуса = 0 протоколом HTTP не предусмотрено. Наверное url "login" не может найти

Comment: Точно ошибка не в url, поскольку я его менял на полный путь http://localhost:8181/library/login, результат тот же, данные приходят, но срабатывает error

Comment: "данные приходят" - данные не приходят - `responseText: ""`

Comment: Не корректно выразился, данные приходят на сервлет, а ответ от сервлета скрипту, видимо не приходит

Comment: SocketConnection работает? Может исключение не позволяет выполнится коду выдачи ответа

Comment: Помогло. Хоть SocketConnection и правильно отправлял данные на сервер, видимо по ходу дела ловил где-то исключение

Comment: А почему сервлет не вылетает после SocketConnection, а доходит до конца, но при этом не происходит отправка данных скрипту? Я поставил точку отладки после SocketConnection и после response.getWriter().println("1"), программа доходит до нее

Comment: Никто не знает что это за SocketConnection. Какое он может оказывать побочное влияние на обработку запроса. Может где-то там в недрах терминирует поток запроса, не давая ему завершить отправку ответа. Кто знает, кто знает...